# Paginated API w/ Table View

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm working on app that gets data from an API that is paginated. As a user scrolls, I want to show more data. I'm kind of stuck where I'm at now. Here's the relevant API Service:

```
struct APIService {
private static let baseURL = "api.com"
private static let clientID = "1234"
private static let clientSecret = "1234"

private enum ResourcePath: CustomStringConvertible {
    case Stream
    case Community

    var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .Stream: return "/api/posts"
        }
    }
}

class PostsWrapper {
    var total_pages: Int?
    var next_page: Int?
    var previous_page: Int?
}


static func getPosts(page: Int, wrapper: PostsWrapper?, result: ([JSON]) -> ()) {
    getAccessToken()

    let urlString = baseURL + ResourcePath.Stream.description + "?page=\(page)"

    let parameters = [
        "client_id": clientID,
        "client_secret": clientSecret,
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString, parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let json = response.result.value {
                let jsonObj = SwiftyJSON.JSON(json ?? [])

                if let data = jsonObj["posts"].arrayValue as [SwiftyJSON.JSON]? {
                    let posts = data
                    result(posts)
                }

                let wrapper = PostsWrapper()
                wrapper.next_page = jsonObj["pagination"]["next_page"].int
                wrapper.previous_page = jsonObj["pagination"]["previous_page"].int
                wrapper.total_pages = jsonObj["pagination"]["total_pages"].int

                print(wrapper.total_pages)

            }
    }
}

}
```

Post View Controller:

```
func loadPosts(page: Int) {
    APIService.getPosts(1) { (JSON) -> () in
        self.userStream = JSON

        self.tableView!.reloadData()

        Loading.stop()

    }
}
```

Any direction would be appreciated to load the next page of posts and show in the table view.

Answer (score 1):

You need check condition in willDisplayCell methods like below

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
           if indexPath.row == <YOUR_ARRAY>.count - 1 { // need to check some extra condition like all data loaded
             //call API here
            //after response from API add you new records to your array and use insertRowsAtIndexPaths method to insert new rows to table
           }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you add -1 when checking the indexPath.row?